# How can I reset my phone without losing everything?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery, system-freeze

I have a Samsung Galaxy S I9000, it keeps lagging; freezing and turning on and off by itself. I want to reset it, if I do will I lose all my photos, contacts etc etc..? I can't figure out how to transfer everything on to my SD card.

Comment: This may be useful to you: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12802/factory-reset-to-restore-performance-what-are-the-disadvantages

Answer (score 5):

If you do a factory reset, your SD card will not be touched.  Your pics, etc will all stay put.  If you've selected your Google account as the default way to store your contacts, they will all repopulated from Google after you set up your phone.

If you want to be sure you're saving settings, etc. download [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) from the Google Playstore and do a full backup.  After you've reset your phone, reinstall *Ti* and then do a restore from back up.  Super simple!

Comment: BE careful! Some Stock ROM's will offer the option to erase the SDCard if about to perform a factory reset, if that's the case, ensure its unchecked! :)

Comment: And keep in mind that *Titanium Backup* requires root. If your device is not rooted, but runs Android 4.0 or higher, take a look at [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/16575).

Answer (score 3):

Resetting your phone to factory settings will clear all the data on your phone memory, that is your contacts, calendars, applications downloaded from android market. 
Factory resetting can be done in settings (Navigation: Settings -> Privacy Settings -> Factory data reset)

Data backup can be done in settings (Navigation: Settings -> Privacy Settings -> Backup my data).
Backup data can be restored after resetting.
Certain applications give the option of data backup, if you have installed any apps from market, check for the option.
Data backup can also be done using the software CD provided with the phone.

Your photos, audio mp3s, and videos will USUALLY reside in SD card and will NOT be erased. But its better you take out the memory card, and then go ahead resetting.

Comment: Your data backup recommendation is not available on most versions of Android.

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways you can reset your Android phone without losing anything. Backup most your stuff on your SD card, and synchronize your phone with a Gmail account so you won't lose any contacts. If you don't want to do that, there's an app called My Backup Pro that can do the same job. You can read more about how to ensure you don't lose any important information with a factory reset [here](http://droidologist.com/how-to-reset-an-android-phone/).

Answer (score -3):

There's an app My Backup Pro which you could use. From the description it allows you to:

> Backup (with schedule option) to our online secure servers, or SD card, your Applications, Photos, Music, Videos, Contacts, Call log, Browser Bookmarks, SMS (text messages), MMS (message attachments), Calendar, System Settings, Home Screens (including shortcut positions), Alarms, Dictionary, Music Playlists, APNs, and more...

You can read more about it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro).